# group matching rows and add a new blank row

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a select query output in MYSQL as below:

| Col 1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Fruit | Orange |
| Fruit | Apple |
| Fruit | Banana |
| Vegetable | Potato |
| Vegetable | Onion |

And I am looking to group matching rows in column 1, and if they do, I want to make that column blank and create a new row, expected output as below:

| Col 1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Fruit |  |
|  | Orange |
|  | Apple |
|  | Banana |
| Vegetable |  |
|  | Potato |
|  | Onion |

Can someone help me with below please?
[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxB92.png)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but have you looked at the GROUP_CONCAT() function of mySQL?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: yes i tried, but it dint give the result as expected